# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set some properties of a div element using javascript, but the properties are not being set, I used the inspect mode in the browser, and It says:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

I already tried to use an ID attribute to get the element and even querySelector method but nothing changes

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var boxElement = document.getElementsByClassName('.box')[0];

        boxElement.style.width = 100;
        boxElement.style.height = 100;
        boxElement.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
    </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: You need to remove that dot. Like this `var boxElement = document.getElementsByClassName('box')`

Comment: Or better yet, use `document.querySelector('.box');` (no `[0]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getElementByClassName implies that the selector's name is a class, so you don't need the dot in front of it. Same as you don't need the # with getElementById.

```
var boxElement = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
```

EDIT: as others are already pointed it out, there is no need for the `getElementByClassName()` function, you can just use the `querySelector()` function in order to avoid an array as the result.

Answer (score 3):

Incorrect syntax. Remove the `.` in the `getElementsByClassName('.box')`.

If you would like to use the class selector you could use `document.querySelectorAll('.box')`

Answer (score 1):

use this (by Id name):

```
document.getElementById('box').setAttribute("style", "width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#f00;");
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

or use this (by class name) :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].setAttribute("style", "width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#f00;");
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="box" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var boxElement = document.querySelector('.box')

    boxElement.style.width = '100px'
    boxElement.style.height = '100px'
    boxElement.style.backgroundColor = '#f00'
</script>
```

This is my resolution for the problem, he needs use a 'px'after CSS code

Comment: Please add some text to explain your answer, a code snippet only won't help the OP to improve :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25766955)

Answer (score 0):

in my case I added extra td in body like below

```
<td>200</td>
```

but forgot to add this in the head section

```
<th>Fees</th>
```